# How do I upload a few simple code files to a GitHub repository?

Tags: git, github, version-control, repository, version

The company I am applying to asked me to send the samples via GitHub, which I have never used. The documentations seem overwhelming with lots of things like command line pull request, push, forking, branching etc. and I don’t have time to go through them right now. So please give me just a simple guide, on how to upload four cpp files from my notebook to Git via Google chrome and link them in an email. Is it possible to do it the same way I upload things to any website?

Comment: I might actually do it from the command line, though there might be a way to do it from the webpage.  Have you tried anything on the GitHub site yet?

Comment: I have created a public repository. When I go to the repository main page, it shows me a lot of code to things like push, pull etc. I understand those are necessary things for professional version control, but right now all I want is to get across four simple files, just once, so that the employer can download them. I hope the process is not too difficult?

Comment: I seem to recall that it's possible to edit source files directly in GitHub, not sure about adding them.  Really, if you have like 20 minutes you could get Git setup locally, and then pushing would be very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** I check the user interface of a newly created repo and the interface might be different from below. In that case, create a `README.MD` first by selecting `We recommend every repository include a README` and just save a blank `README`

I assume you have little to no idea how VCS works? So let's try to solve this without any commands first.

In your project repo look for `Upload files` located at the top right just below the page header. Please check screenshot below.

[image]

And there you go. You've successfully uploaded your files without any commands.

If however you want to use git bash, please check ff steps:

1. Create public repo.
2. Install `git` on your machine.
3. From git bash, execute `git clone <project>` where `<project>` is the URL when you click the `Clone or download` button on the above image.
4. Paste the files on the folder that was created by `git clone`
5. `git add .`
6. `git commit -m "<your commit message"`
7. `git push`

For simplification, use the `http` part when cloning but you might be ask for your username/password a couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

You asked in a comment for a simple way to upload once, so the potential employer can see it. It sounds like you don't actually need full on version control, I suggest using gists, which is a feature on github to quickly share code files or snippets of text. As long as the employer is ok with gists, it would probably be easier.

https://gist.github.com

Note the "add file" button in the bottom left.